# Hosting Website on Ubuntu, cant get it to load on any other machine

Tags: networking, server, apache2, webserver

Im hosting an instance of Snipe it on a ubuntu machine.  I can hit the webpage just fine on the host machine, If I try and navigate to it on any other machine on the network I get a "This site can't be reached".  The machine is ping-able and when I throw in the IP in the browser it does resolve to a FQDN.  Any thoughts on what I may be missing?  The machine itself is also pingable and the firewall is turned off.

Comment: Install `tracepath`. Read `msn tracepath`. You can use `tracepath` to see where a `TCP:80` packet goes.

Comment: We need to know more about your webserver configuration. Does the application run on port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS)? Is the message "This site can't be reached" a browser's own message or does it come from the server? (you can recognize this by how it looks like). Do developer tools in browser show anything about headers? Maybe your webserver listens on localhost interface only? If your application runs on plain HTTP, try telnetting to port 80 of your machine from other machine in the network and simulate a HTTP request, check if you get any response at all.

Comment: What Ubuntu product & release are you hosting on?